# TableViewCell doesn't update correctly

Tags: xcode4, uitableview, ios5, nscell

I have this tableviewcell.m to configure my cells.
It is configuring the text and information correctly but I just can't get it to update the color according to some other information.
Here's the code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {        
    priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    priceLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    [priceLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    if ([account.income isEqualToString:@"income"]){
        [priceLabel setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    } else if ([account.income isEqualToString:@"expense"]) {
        [priceLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    } //label, alignment, font are working correctly
    //but the if statement doesn't get there
}
```

The color though, not working at all.
It seems to me that the if statement is being completely ignored.
Could anyone help me to understand why or suggest a better programming approach ?

Here's the cell for row code. I don't know if it will help because they aren't in the same file. Here I'm only referencing my tableviewcell file:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    //  create a TableViewCell, then set its account to the account for the current row.
    static NSString *AccountCellIdentifier = @"AccountCellIdentifier";

    TableViewCell *accountCell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AccountCellIdentifier];
    if (accountCell == nil) {
        accountCell = [[[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AccountCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        accountCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    [self configureCell:accountCell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return accountCell; 
}

//and here the cell config
- (void)configureCell:(TableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Configure the cell
    Account *account = (Account *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.account = account; 
}
```

Many thanks !

Here's the code where i get the texts:

```
- (void)setAccount:(Account *)newAccount {
if (newAccount != account) {
    [account release];
    account = [newAccount retain];
}
nameLabel.text = account.name;
accountLabel.text = Account.accounttype;
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *stringcost = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:account.cost];
priceLabel.text = stringcost;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a UILabel with a frame rect of { 0, 0, 0, 0 } ???

Comment: Can you show the code for your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method in your question up there?

Comment: @Michael thanks for helping so far. I edited the question to show you the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. But i don't think it's going to help because I have a TableViewCell.m where I'm trying to configure this...

Comment: You're right... it doesn't help. What I am really trying to find out is where in your code do you assign the text values to the `priceLabel` UILabel in your TableViewCell and what does *that code* look like. One more thing. Please make sure the code you paste into your questions is formatted nicely (check the preview below the text entry window). I've had to clean up the code you've pasted twice now.w

Comment: Justupdated again showing where I set the texts. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Should I try doing that If statement on the setAccount function ? I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I knew I was missing something simple.
All I had to do is "move" that If... statement to where the implementation of the cell is setting the text. There and only there it will update the color (or anything else) so here's my final code that's working perfectly now...

```
- (void)setAccount:(Account *)newAccount {
if (newAccount != account) {
[account release];
account = [newAccount retain];
}
nameLabel.text = account.name;
accountLabel.text = Account.accounttype;
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *stringcost = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:account.cost];
priceLabel.text = stringcost;
if ([account.income isEqualToString:@"income"]){
    [priceLabel setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
} else if ([account.income isEqualToString:@"expense"]) {
    [priceLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
} //this will give me green text color for income and red text color for expense
}
```

Special thanks for Michael Dauterman who inspired me to stay awake for hours through the night  'till my function is actually working.